# Implementation of concepts in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, enable-if

I'd seen the Bjarne stroustrup's talk named "Concepts the future of generic programming" and I thought maybe I can write "Concepts" in C++17...
But I'm a C programmer I've start with C++ about 6 months ago... so I don't know why but I've got e trouble with this code. Somebody can help me?

I'd implemented the Addable's concept with a shortly tmp code...
The idea is that will be in C++20 will be something like this:

```
  template<typename T>
  concept Summable = requires(T x) { x + x; };

  template<typename T> requires Summable<T>
  T sum(T n1, T n2) {
     return n1 + n2;
  }
```

And this code is what actually have in C++17:

```
 template <typename, typename, typename = void>
 struct Addable : std::false_type {};

 template <typename T, typename U>
 struct Addable < T, U,
                 std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>()+std::declval<U&>())> > 
             : std::true_type {};
```

The top's code compile and works, but when I whrite the following code doesn't compile...

```
 template<typename Head, typename ... Tail>
 auto sum(Head h, Tail ... args) {
    static_assert(Addable<Head, Tail...>::value, "Requires addable objects");
    return h+(args+...);
 }
```

Comment: `Addable<Head, Tail...>::value` isn't going to work if `Tail` has 2+ elements in it.

Comment: But this code compiles. What does your compiler say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might change you assertion to

```
template <typename Head, typename ... Tail>
auto sum(Head h, Tail ... args) {
    static_assert((Addable<Head, Tail>::value || ...), "Requires addable objects");
    return (h + ... + args);
}
```

as your traits only works for 2 types.

Notice that SFINAE looks more like *concept* than `static_assert`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code [does work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3372212407e6b743) as long as you only provide two arguments to `sum`.

The problem is that when you call something like `sum(1, 2, 3)`, `Addable<Head, Tail...>` becomes `Addable<int, int, int>`, which doesn't match your `Addable<T, U, void>` partial specialization.  If you call `sum` with more than three arguments then there's no `Addable` template that matches at all, since `Addable` only accepts three template parameters.

If you want to be able to deal with more than two arguments, you'll need a different approach.  This is what I came up with.  It uses a similar approach to what you used, just with an extra layer indirection to support more than two arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename = void>
struct Helper : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Helper<T, U, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>())>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename, typename...>
struct Addable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... V>
struct Addable<T, U, V...> : std::conditional_t<Addable<T, U>::value,
                                                Addable<U, V...>,
                                                std::false_type> {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Addable<T, U> : Helper<T, U> {};

template<typename Head, typename ... Tail>
auto sum(Head h, Tail ... args) {
    static_assert(Addable<Head, Tail...>::value, "Requires addable objects");
    return h+(args+...);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f28462b7db67554b)